# How to convert Date Format in php eg 2010-01-30 to Jan. 30, 2010

Tags: php, function, date

I am pulling a date from a MySQL database that is formatted `2010-01-30`. What I need is to convert it to format `Jan. 30, 2010` or `January 30, 2010`.

Is there a simple way to do this in PHP?

Comment: All bets are in ladies & gentlemen. It's off to the races...

Comment: [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the date exists as '2010-01-30' in `$date_variable` variable:

`$formatted_date = date( 'M d, Y', strtotime( $date_variable ) );`

[`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) converts any date string into the # of seconds since UNIX epoch. We feed this back into date() as second parameter with the format string 'M d, Y'. Additional formatting options [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$date = '2010-01-30';
$dt = new DateTime($date);
echo $dt->format('M. d, Y');
```

Supported Formats: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php

Answer (score 1):

It's simple way to do that it's one of solution:

```
<?php echo date("M. d, Y",strtotime("2010-01-30")); ?>
```

It will give you: Jan. 30, 2010
If it's all you need - click solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$date=new DateTime('2010-01-30');
echo $date->format('F d, Y')."<BR>";
echo $date->format('M. d, Y');
?>
```

Comment: TIP: Add a dot in `echo $date->format('M d, Y');` just after the `M` --- *"What I need is to convert it to format Jan. 30, 2010"* <= OP ;-)